# How to insert multiple arguments in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have this project I'm working on and I'm trying to implement multiprocessing. I can't quite get it to work because the function I'm trying to have it run requires multiple arguments. Basically, there are sites that `processDFStandardCurve` processes and that is the only variable that changes in each test that multiprocess would be running. Those different site names are stored as `siteIDList`.

```
def multiprocess (cursor, testsDict, optionsDict, outputPath, calculated_pdf, stationToPriority, result):
    siteIDList = []
    for line in result:
        siteID = line[3]
        nbsNum = line[2]
        if siteID != "":
            siteIDList.append(siteID)
        else:
            siteIDList.append(nbsNum)
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    p.starmap(processDFStandardCurve, siteIDList,  cursor, testsDict, optionsDict, outputPath, calculated_pdf, stationToPriority)
```

`processDFStandardCurve` is as follows:

```
def processDFStandardCurve(cursor, siteID, testsDict, optionsDict, outputPath, calculated_pdf, stationToPriority):
```

It all stops after the `p.map()` call.

When using `starmap` it throws this error

```
TypeError: starmap() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 9 were given
```

Answer (score 2):

To invoke [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) you want to do something like this:

```
p.starmap(processDFStandardCurve, [(siteIDList,  cursor, testsDict, optionsDict, outputPath, calculated_pdf, stationToPriority)])
```

The arguments must be in their own iterable. We can see this in the documentation (linked above) of the signature:

```
starmap(func, iterable[, chunksize])
```

This means it takes two required and one optional. The iterable provided here are a list of all the arguments that are unpacked and sent to `func`. Each item in the outer iterable is passed to the function provided in the first value. Therefore the inner iterable should be your arguments.

In your case you need to modify your code somewhat:

```
def multiprocess (cursor, testsDict, optionsDict, outputPath, calculated_pdf, stationToPriority, result):
    arg_list = []
    for line in result:
        id = line[3] if line[3] != "" else line[2]
        site_args = (id, cursor, testsDict, optionsDict, outputPath, calculated_pdf, stationToPriority)
        arg_list.append(site_args)

    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    p.starmap(processDFStandardCurve, arg_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap). You can pass multiple arguments to it.

Comment: I've tried starmap, but it says that I can use 3 to 4 arguments but there are 9 or so. I'm not sure if there is a solution for that?

Comment: "three to four"? starmap has no limit on number of arguments. Can you show us how you tried and how it failed?

Comment: @EthanMcQ, ...I suspect that maybe you passed the arguments directly on starmap's parameter list, instead of making them list entries inside the iterable parameter. There shouldn't be any hardcoded limit to how many items can be inside `iterable`, or how many parameters each of those items can have.

Comment: I just edited the post to show the error with starmap

Comment: Starmap does have a constrained number of arguments: self, a function, an iterator of iterators of arguments, and an optional chunk size. That's where the 3-4 comes from.